# How to change FPS in getusermedia with the 640*480 resolution?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, frame-rate, getusermedia

I changed the FPS in [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) but resolution also got changed. How can I reduce the FPS, while keeping the resolution at 640 × 480?

I tried the code below, but the video is displayed in a different resolution.

```js
var constraints = {
  video: {
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    frameRate: {
      ideal: 10,
      max: 15
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var constraints = {
  video: {
    width: {exact: 640},
    height: {exact: 480},
    frameRate: {
      ideal: 10,
      max: 15
    }
  }
};
```

Note, though, not all browsers on all platforms downscale to arbitrary dimensions, leaving you picking among discrete native modes instead. Seeing resolution changes is usually a sign of this, because of how [fitness distance](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#dfn-fitness-distance) is calculated. So be prepared with a fallback if this fails.

A better strategy may be to obtain the camera in the resolution you want first, then use `applyConstraints` to reduce its framerate:

```
await stream.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints({
  width: {exact: 640},
  height: {exact: 480},
  frameRate: {ideal: 10, max: 15}
]);
```

That way if it fails you still have a stream.

Comment: If this is needed for webrtc, you can also use the new Transceiver-API, more precisely the [sendEncodings-Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpEncodingParameters), to set Framerate and VideoScaling, by using `yourRTCPeerConnection.addTransceiver('video', {kind: 'sendonly', sendEncodings: [{frameRate: 15, scaleResolutionDownBy: 2}]})`

Comment: @nasskalte.juni I think you mean [maxFramerate](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcrtpencodingparameters-maxframerate)? Beware support for it is spotty atm. Useful for simulcast (different framerates per layer).

Comment: yeah, I forgot the 'max'-prefix, good catch. Currently, you can only use it with newer chrome versions, but as you said, it might come in handy for simulcast-scenarios.